# Rendering show_placeholder on app_hook model without reverse_id

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I have a news app served through an apphook to django-cms. It has a common placeholder that needs to be rendered through its articles

I've tried to use

```
{% block left-slogan %}
{% show_placeholder "left-slogan" inherit %}
{% endblock %}
```

I've also tried to place the reverse_id of the apphooked page and add an app_name to cms_app.py, both to no avail.

Here's my cms_app.py

```
class NewsApphook(CMSApp):
    name = _("News")
    urls = ["news.urls"]

apphook_pool.register(NewsApphook)
```

My urls.py

```
from .views import NewsView, NewsDetailView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', NewsView.as_view(), name='news'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>(.*))/$', NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='news_detail'),
)
```

**EDIT** Here's my full placeholder tree

base.html

```
{% load sekizai_tags cms_tags (...) %}
(...)
{% block left-slogan %}{% placeholder "left-slogan" %}{% endblock %}
(...)
```

default.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
(...)
{% block left-slogan %}
{% placeholder "left-slogan" or %}
    {% show_placeholder "left-slogan" "index" %}
{% endplaceholder %}
{% endblock %}
(...)
```

news_detail.html

```
(...)
{% block left-slogan %}{% show_placeholder "left-slogan" inherit %}{% endblock %}
(...)
```

Does anyone know how to do a show_placeholder of an apphooked view inside its children?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to call `render_placeholder`? http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.2/extending_cms/placeholders.html#templates

Comment: It's not a PlaceholderField. It's an actual placeholder provided by the "hooked" template in CMS

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I would think your app hooked page would probably need to extend the template where the "left-slogan" placeholder exits, or you would need to move the content for "left-cplaceholder" into a shared template that you could reference by id.

Comment: It already extends. I edited my post to reflect the tree up to its base. My objective was to use inherit instead of "id" because the App might change page in the future. However, I'm starting to hate this idea and go for id after all. Please give that answer so that I can rate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to extend the template where the `left-slogan` placeholder exists, or you would need to move the content for the "left-placeholder" into a shared template that you could reference by id.